# How to bypass the Google API Website authentication flow

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I have a Python script that goes into my Gmail inbox and looks for certain emails based off the subject line. I would like to automate this process; however, my credentials seem to expire on a weekly basis. Whenever they expire and I run my script, it opens up my browser and prompts me to authorize my app. Is there anyway this can be bypassed so that I can automate my script and not have to constantly authenticate my app through the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: You may try to work via IMAP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is in the testing phase the refresh token will expire after a week. If you want your refresh token to last longer you will need to set your application to production and go though the verification process.

if this is a google workspace email account then you should consider using a service account for authorization and setting up domain wide delegation.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority  So I was able to give my service account domain wide delegation and also publish the app; however, since I dont have a google workspace admin account it does not seem like I am able to do steps 2-4 in the link above from the google docs.. Is there anyway I can do this without an admin account?

Comment: Gmail api **only** works with google workspace domain emails, you cant use it with a standard user email.  You need the admin of the domain to grant your service account access to your account.   You cant do it without the admin. why not contact them and ask.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by creating a google workspace account, and adding that account to my project.. I would not have been able to do it without your guidance, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: please remember to accept the anwser if it helped